# using mermaid.js with angular causes compilation errors

Tags: angular, npm, compiler-errors, mermaid

I use Angular 16 and I want to render a mermaid string in the browser.
To replicate the error, I created a brand new Angular 16 app with the cli and installed the npm package via `npm i mermaid` and tried to just initialize it like this:

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as mermaid from 'mermaid';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit
{
  ngOnInit(): void
  {
    mermaid.initialize({
      startOnLoad: true,
      theme: 'dark',
      flowchart: {
        useMaxWidth: false,
        htmlLabels: true
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Here I get the error `TS2339: Property 'initialize' does not exist on type 'typeof import("C:/Users/xxx/node_modules/mermaid/dist/mermaid")'.`

If I use

```js
mermaid.default.initialize
```

instead, the type errors go away at least.
When running Angular just with the initialize code, the following errors occur:
[image]

[image]

I tried installing both types but this brings new errors:
[image]

Am I using this library completely wrong? Is it not supposed to be used with Angular?

I tried installing mermaid.js and initializing it. I expected it to work and not throw errors.

## Edit

I got it to run by having this in my index.html:

```js
  <script type="module">
    import mermaid from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10/dist/mermaid.esm.min.mjs';
    mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad: true });
  </script>
```

However this really isn't a great solution as I want the app to work offline and this script itself import different script internally. Importing it in the script tag from the node modules folder did not work.